# Let $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, and $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z \in U$ , then $f$ is open mapp in U.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

Let $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, and $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z \in U$ , then $f$  is open mapp in U. (Send open sets to open sets).

I'm not quite sure how to write the arguments. But, using the inverse function theorem, then there exists an open neighborhood $U'$ for $z_0\in U$ and $V'$ for $f(z_0)$ where $g:V' \rightarrow U'$ is the inverse of $f$ and $g$ is analytic.

For $A\subset U'$, an open set, since $g$ is analytic then g is continuous, then the inverse image $g^{-1}(A)$ is an open set. But, there exists a set $B\subset V'$ such that $B=g^{-1}(A)$.

Comment: any analytic functions is open unless it is constant

Comment: It's simply the open mapping theorem.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof of the Open Mapping Theorem? There are several ways to do this. Do you know Rouche's Theorem?

Comment: @Matematleta, the restriction is, only use Inverse Function Theorem. I did not write it above

Comment: Take V open subset of U.  Use the inverse function theorem at every point of V to show that f(V) is a union of open sets.